# Doubts with TSLint

Tags: angular, ionic3, tslint

I have some doubts with TSLint with ionic.

I have installed official TSLint rules for ionic from:

https://github.com/ionic-team/tslint-ionic-rules

Then I have installed globally tslint with:

```
npm install tslint typescript -g
```

How can I test my project and obtain the results with the CLI?

I have already tried with:

```
tslint -p /pathToRootProject > test.txt
```

But I am not sure if this is correct way.

On the other hand I have tried to do:

```
tslint --fix semicolon
```

But it returns:

```
'semicolon' does not exist. This will be an error in TSLint 6.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command line to work with my project.

`tslint --config ./tslint.json --project ./tsconfig.json --force --format stylish`

--config and point to my tslint.json file with all the different rules I want to enforce.

--project uses the tsconfig.json, Typescript configuration for which files to build, options in Typescript to use with Linting, etc.

--force will return a status code of 0 (no errors even if the linter finds some) so my build process will continue.

--format to use the stylish formatter to get a nicer output that I prefer to use to clean up my code.

The complete [TSLint command line interface guide](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/) is here.

Comment: And to fix a specific problem like `semicolon`?

Comment: I believe the --fix addresses all the Lint problems that it can.  There does not appear to be a parameter on the CLI that would fix just one lint problem, so the addition of the --fix the above command line would attempt to fix every problem that can be fixed.  The --fix can be anywhere on the command line, so it can be before the --force, at the end, etc. as long as it does not go between an option and the value (IE: --config ./tslint.json).